# Consuming Web Services - Confusion on Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I recently added a remote WSDL file for a web service to my app_webreferences folder.

I can see all the objects in that WSDL file - however, the problem is that the company that i'm integrating with sent me two urls.

1. a wsdl: https://website.com/SOAP/Queue?wsdl
2. an endpoint: https://website.com/SOAP/Queue?api_key=xxxxxx

So - when I added the app_webreference I used the first url - it worked, added it to project.

I then proceeded to setup my bindings as such:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="QueueWebServiceBinding">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

My client endpoint looks like this:

```
  <endpoint address="https://website.com/SOAP/Queue?wsdl"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QueueWebServiceBinding"
    contract="MyWebService" name="QueueWebServicePort" />
</client>
```

The thing is, I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I'm not sure where I should use the endpoint url (#2) in any of this. It seems that when I switch it out in the endpoint address (#2) above I receive a response of:

`...<env:Fault..... does not contain operation meta data for ... </env:Fault>...`

I'm really confused on how to set this all up.

Another thing to note, they do require authentication... so my actual code looks something like this...

```
MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var t = client.doSomething();
```

I've been googling/searching stackoverflow for the past few hours but have had little success figuring out the right way to set this all up.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The first endpoint is for the WSDL.   The second endpoint is for the actual service itself.  So you need to change your endpoint in your config file as follows:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://website.com/SOAP/Queue?api_key=xxxxxx"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="QueueWebServiceBinding"
            contract="MyWebService" name="QueueWebServicePort" />
</client>
```

Since you've already tried switching out the endpoint, try using the second endpoint to add the service reference and see if that works (if you haven't already).

If neither of those work, then I'd suggest talking to the vendor's support staff to see if they can help, since they should know everything you need to do to access the service.

Comment: Hi Tim - when I do that setup I receive `does not contain operation meta data for` returnned in a env:fault - the problem with the vendor is they aren't familiar with .net - thanks for your advice.